# Why is Rails 4 caching all scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there something changed in Rails 4 due to which the following doesn't work as expected:

```
    def self.top_experts(timeframe = 1.week.ago, limit = 5)
      Answer.where('created_at between ? and ?', timeframe, Time.now)
            .group(:user_id)
            .order('sum(score) DESC')
            .limit(limit)
            .includes(:user)
            .collect{|x| x.user}
    end
```

For some reason it isn't updating every week (even though a manual check does show the list returned should be different).

The query is intended to return experts who have the highest rated answers in the last 7 days..

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: Just updated the question.

Comment: I think the `group` is the problem but not sure how to resolve this without grouping on the user_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that Answer had a default_scope which was screwing up this query, so doing `Answer.unscoped` fixed it.

Jesus! This appeared to be effecting many other queries as well. I guess using `default_scope` is a big no-no.